# Export entire Logical Data Model from GoodData

Tags: json, business-intelligence, gooddata

In this https://developer.gooddata.com/article/data-modeling-api there is a logical data model and its corresponding JSON. However, I can't seem to find out how to extract JSON from a logical data model via the REST API. Is there a way to do this other than using the single load interface (which would be very inefficient)?

For the record, my end goal is to make a tool that extracts that JSON (which would be in dev), then post that to the ldm manager2, and then apply the suggested changes through the returned MaQL to production. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this works only for Getting or Updating the entire Project. Anyway you can GET all model definition by simple API call. See the documentation:

http://docs.gooddatadrafts.apiary.io/

There is a GET request which is asynchronous. You can build some logic on the top of that on your end. You can get all models, store per datasets information, but at the end you need to POST the "final version" and all updates will be applied.

Let me know if I can help you with anything!

Regards,

JT